# MySQL Error 1068 multiple primary key defined

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1068

There is an existed table that, and I want to alter the table by adding only 1 primary key directly, but the system shows Error 1068 multiple primary key defined. Where are the multiple primary keys???
I tried to drop the table and create+alter again, and it works. I just wonder why I can't run them separately？

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_DB.EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION (
EMP_ID VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_NAME VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_NUMBER VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_SEX VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_BIRTH TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
EMP_TEL VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_WECHAT VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_EMAIL VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_SCHOOL VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_GRADE VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
EMP_MAJOR VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL ,
UPDAT_DATE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL );

ALTER TABLE MY_DB.EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION PRIMARY KEY (EMP_NUMBER)
```

Error:

> Error Code: 1068. Multiple primary key defined

[image]

Comment: Which column(s) are you trying to add key on?

Comment: When you're asking for help, you’ll get more/better answers if you don’t post screenshots or photos. Cut & paste the text directly into the message.

Why?
1. It's easier for people to read it.
2. It allows those reading it to cut & paste the text, making it easier to work on solving your problem.
3. It makes it searchable, so that someone can find this thread when Googling for information in the future.
4. A screen reader can't read a picture which limits access to some in our community.

Comment: There must be something you didn't show us that added a primary key before this. You have to remove that PK first.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a primary key twice.

Somewhere, somehow, you have already added a primary key to the `EMPLOYEE_TIME_STATUS` table. We can't tell how. Also the `CREATE TABLE` statement you showed us up top is for a table `EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION`, which will have no bearing on the `EMPLOYEE_TIME_STATUS` table.

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE` command doesn't add a primary key. Where do you see it being done twice?

Comment: See in my comment the `ALTER TABLE` statement from your post. That `ALTER TABLE` is adding a primary key.

Comment: We need to see the exact error message you got. Please cut & paste it from your DB client into the question, because we can't see it all.

Comment: The error message in the screenshot is exactly the same as the question title.

Comment: I've added it to the question for them.

Comment: Somewhere, somehow, you have already added a primary key to the EMPLOYEE_TIME_STATUS table. We can't tell how. Also the CREATE TABLE statement you showed us up top is for a table EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION, which will have no bearing on the EMPLOYEE_TIME_STATUS table.

Comment: yes，I have 5 different tables. I posted the wrong one, but they are basically the same. They all show up with this error, if I alter them separately.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I checked it again, and I realize I must have done primary key before but I forgot, so I am doing it twice now.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Which Mysql version are you using? If it's 8.0 ver, MySQL supports generated invisible primary keys for any InnoDB table that is created without an explicit primary key, When the **sql_generate_invisible_primary_key** server system variable is set to ON, the MySQL server automatically adds a generated invisible primary key (GIPK) to any such table:

> mysql> SELECT @@sql_generate_invisible_primary_key;

And should query:

> mysql> SHOW COLUMNS FROM EMPLOYEE_TIME_STATUS;

to determine if another PK exists.